# PHP IF si se dan dos condiciones buscador

Tags: javascript, ajax, buscador

estoy haciendo un buscador, con 3 variables, estas las paso con Ajax pero no logro que me de el resultado uniendo dos de ellas.
les paso el codigo a ver si me pueden dar una mano, desde ya muchas gracias.

```
<?php
require("php/db.php");
///////// parametros que recibo del formulario /////////////
$constante ="";
$priceRange = $_POST['price_range'];
$marcas = $_POST['marcas'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

////////// condiciones //////////

if(!empty($_POST['marcas']))
    {
    $constante = "WHERE marca_pro = $marcas";
    }
else if(!empty($_POST['cat']))
    {
    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat";
    }
else if(!empty($_POST["cat"]) && !empty($_POST["marcas"]))
    {
    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat AND marca_pro = $marcas";
    }
else{
    $constante = "";
}
////////// consulta ///////////
$consulta1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM productos Left Join marcas ON productos.marca_pro = marcas.id_marcas Left Join combo ON productos.combo_pro = combo.id_combo $constante");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<!-- combo --><div class=\"card mb-4\">
$marcas
$cat
    <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"images/combos/".$row['foto_combo']."\" alt=\"Card image cap\">
    <div class=\"card-body\">
    <div class=\"row\">

<!-- productos --><div class=\"col-xl-6 col-lg-6\">
    <div class=\"marca\">".$row['nombre_marcas']."</div>
    <div class=\"desc\">".$row['nombre_pro']."</div>
    <div class=\"precio\">$ ".$row['precio_pro']."</div>
</div><!-- end productos -->
</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end combo -->";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

es error en la logica:

ya que la primera coincidencia es la valida. en este caso las solo tomaria la primera en el orden osea `marcas` y omitiria las siguientes ya que ya hubo un true y no debe porque continuar evaluando si se obtiene `cat` solo evaluara hasta `cat`!
**solucion:**

```
if(!empty($_POST["cat"]) && !empty($_POST["marcas"])) 
    {
    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat AND marca_pro = $marcas"; 
    }
else if(!empty($_POST['cat']))
    {
    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat";
    }
else if(!empty($_POST['marcas']))
    {
    $constante = "WHERE marca_pro = $marcas";
    }
else{
    $constante = "";
}
```

Comment: gracias Bryro, o sea que cuando le agregue la tercera condición tengo que hacerlo en el primer if?

Comment: Anda, sos un genio, no te puedo explicar las horas que estuve intentando esto, soy nuevo en el tema

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice el compañero tiene toda la razón. Como norma, cuando apliques varios posibles criterios sobre los mismos datos, expresa siempre primero los criterios más "exigentes".

Además, ten cuidado que los valores de `$_POST` (o `$_GET`, si a eso vamos) lleguen, y que no sean cadenas vacías, o sólo con espacios en blanco (a mi me ha pasado). Por ejemplo, puedes poner:

```
$cat_pro = (isset($_POST('cat_pro'))?trim($_POST('cat_pro')):'';
$marca_pro = (isset($_POST('marca_pro'))?trim($_POST('marca_pro')):'';
if ($cat_pro > '' && $marca_pro > '') {
   $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat_pro AND marca_pro = $marca_pro "; 
} elseif ($cat_pro > '') {
   $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat_pro "; 
} elseif ($marca_pro > '') {
   $constante = "WHERE marca_pro = $marca_pro ";
} else {
   $constante = '';
}
```

Es más engorroso, pero te queda más asegurado todo.
Un saludo.

Comment: Genial José lo implementaré muchas gracias